# Shopping List program: In VIM "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", but Codeblocks works

Tags: c++, vim, codeblocks

Hope your day is going well.

I am a bit of a noobie when it comes to programming so please bear with me. I have two problems. I am attempting to create a program consisting of 5 files: items.h, items.cpp, list.h, list.cpp, and main. There is an Item class and a List class. The object of this program is to create a shopping list that allows the user to enter an Item Name, the Item Unit, cost per Unit, and then add it to the list. The program also allows you to remove an item by its name. **We cannot use vectors**.

Problem 1: What I have so far will run in Codeblocks, but when I run it in VIM, I get the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)."

Problem 2: I also come across an error when I attempt to add another variable to use in main, such as amountToBuy (contains the int number of Items user wants to buy)--when added, the program in Codeblocks won't run, stating "std::bad_alloc". I've commented some things out so the program will run.

I am at a complete loss and don't know which lines are causing the issues or how I would go about fixing things. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LIST_H_INCLUDED
#include "items.h"
#include <string>

class List
{
    private:
        int arrayPosition;
        int arraySize;
        Item* itemsOnList = new Item[arraySize];
    public:
        List();
        void addItem(Item);
        void removeItem(std::string ri);
        void displayList();
    }; 
#endif // LIST_H_INCLUDED
```

**list.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
#include "items.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/*******************************************************************

List::List()
Constructor initializes List size to 4 as default

*******************************************************************/
List::List()
{
    arraySize = 4;
    arrayPosition = 0;
}


/*******************************************************************

void List::addItem(Item)
This function adds the specified Item to the List

*******************************************************************/
void List::addItem(Item i)
{
    //x2 arraySize when arrayPosition gets too close to arraySize
    if (arrayPosition == arraySize)
    {
        //doubling arraySize since we need more space
        arraySize *= 2;

        //tempList to hold the old List's items
        Item* tempList = new Item[arraySize];

        //transferring information to tempList
        for (int a = 0; a < arrayPosition; a++)
        {
            tempList[a] = itemsOnList[a];
        }

        delete[] itemsOnList;

        //transferring data from temp List back to Old list
        itemsOnList = tempList;

        delete[] tempList;

        //adding next item to list
        itemsOnList[arrayPosition++] = i;
    }
    else
    {
        //adding next item to list
        itemsOnList[arrayPosition++] = i;
    }
}


/*******************************************************************

void List::removeItem(std::string)
This function removes the specified Item to the List

*******************************************************************/
void List::removeItem(std::string ri)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < arrayPosition; a++)
    {
        if (itemsOnList[a].getItemName() == ri)
        {
            //moving the rest of the items down one position
            //to take the removed item's spot
            for (int b = a; b < arrayPosition; b++)
            {
                itemsOnList[b] = itemsOnList[b+1];
            }
            //decreasing arrayPosition by one because Item was removed
            --arrayPosition;
        }
    }
}

/*******************************************************************

void List::displayList()
This function displays the List

*******************************************************************/
void List::displayList()
{
    std::cout << "The following Items are on your Grocery List\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayPosition; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Item name: " << itemsOnList[i].getItemName() << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Number to buy: " << itemsOnList[i].getNumberToBuy() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**items.h**

```
#ifndef ITEMS_H_INCLUDED
#define ITEMS_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class Item
{
    private:
        std::string itemName;
        //int numberToBuy;
    public:
        Item();
        Item(std::string);
        //setters
        void setItemName(std::string);
        //void setNumberToBuy(int);
        //getters
        std::string getItemName();
};

#endif // ITEMS_H_INCLUDED
```

**items.cpp**

```
#include "items.h"

Item::Item()
{
    itemName = "empty";
    //numberToBuy = 0;
}

//this constructor accepts a string and an int
Item::Item(std::string in)
{
    itemName = in;
    //numberToBuy = ntb;
}

//setters
void Item::setItemName(std::string in)
{
    itemName = in;
}

/*
void Item::setNumberToBuy(int ntb)
{
    numberToBuy = ntb;
}
*/

//getters
std::string Item::getItemName()
{
    return itemName;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
#include "items.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int menuChoice, subMenuChoice;
    std::string itemName, removeItem;
    bool exit = false;
    List newList;

    //introduction
    std::cout << "Welcome to your Grocery List!\n\n";

    do
    {
        //menu
        std::cout << "* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n\n";
        std::cout << "To select a menu item, please select its corresponding number.\n\n";

        //menu prompts and storing the choice
        std::cout << "1. Add items to Grocery List\n";
        std::cout << "2. Remove items from Grocery List\n";
        std::cout << "3. Display Grocery List\n";
        std::cout << "4. Exit\n\n";

        std::cout << "* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \n\n";
        std::cout << "Menu choice: ";
        std::cin >> menuChoice;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        //menu choice break-away section
        if (menuChoice == 1)
        {
            do
            {
                std::cout << "Please enter the name of the item: ";
                std::cin >> itemName;

                //std::cout << "Please enter the unit (cans, lbs, oz): ";
                //std::cin >> itemUnit;

                //std::cout << "Please enter number to buy: ";
                //std::cin >> amountToBuy;

                Item theItem(itemName);

                newList.addItem(theItem);

                std::cout << "Would you like to add another item? For YES type 1 | For NO type 0: ";
                std::cin >> subMenuChoice;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            while(subMenuChoice == 1);
        }
        else if (menuChoice == 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter the name of the item you want to remove: ";
            std::cin >> removeItem;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            newList.removeItem(removeItem);
        }
        else if (menuChoice == 3)
        {
            newList.displayList();
        }
        else if (menuChoice == 4)
        {
            exit = true;
            std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while (exit == false);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Important bit that is best learned early: Many programming mistakes can result in looking like they work sometimes. This means it may "work" consistently with one compiler or on one computer and never on another or it might "work" part of the time, and stop "working" suddenly for no obvious reason. The truth is it never "worked". Anyway, when you find something that "works" under build system 1 and not build system 2, it's almost never the build system's fault. It might "work" when you test it, but not when the teacher does. Fun, huh?

Comment: In the list class definition `Item* itemsOnList = new Item[arraySize];` shouldn't work. `arraySize` hasn't been set yet, so no one knows what will happen. You could build an array of size 0, four billion, -42, or any other valid `int`. Most of those will blow up instantly.

Comment: @user4581301 You can't actually declare an array with a negative size but you have hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Agreed. It will blow up instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
class List
{
private:
    int arrayPosition;
    int arraySize;
    Item* itemsOnList = new Item[arraySize];
public:
    List();
    void addItem(Item);
    void removeItem(std::string ri);
    void displayList();
};
```

`Item* itemsOnList = new Item[arraySize];` will execute before the body of the constructor so by the time

```
List::List()
{
    arraySize = 4;
    arrayPosition = 0;
}
```

runs and `arraySize` is set to 4, `itemsOnList` has already been assigned an array of unknown size or the program has crashed.

A simple fix for this is

```
class List
{
private:
    int arrayPosition;
    int arraySize;
    Item* itemsOnList;
public:
    List();
    void addItem(Item);
    void removeItem(std::string ri);
    void displayList();
};
```

and

```
List::List()
{
    arraySize = 4;
    arrayPosition = 0;
    itemsOnList = new Item[arraySize]
}
```

or

```
List::List():
    arrayPosition(0),
    arraySize(4),
    itemsOnList(new Item[arraySize])
{
}
```

The second uses the unfortunately under-taught [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). This is often the best approach because it ensures that the object is fully constructed before entering the body of the constructor.  For complex objects this prevents having to redo any work performed by default constructors that are used to make certain the object is valid before use.

Edit: A note on the Member Initializer List link above. The first third might look as though written in Martian. Skip down to the Explanation section and start reading there, then go back up to the specifics, if needed.

In `addItem` the following will also cause problems:

```
    Item* tempList = new Item[arraySize]; //created new array

    //transferring information to tempList
    for (int a = 0; a < arrayPosition; a++)
    {
        tempList[a] = itemsOnList[a]; //copying old to new
    }

    delete[] itemsOnList; //free old list storage

    //transferring data from temp List back to Old list
    itemsOnList = tempList; // assign new list to old list


    delete[] tempList; // whoops. Freed new list storage
```

For a brief period of time `tempList` and `itemsOnList` point to the same storage, so `delete`ing either pointer will free the storage for both. Solution: Don't `delete[] tempList;`

In `RemoveItem`:

```
for (int b = a; b < arrayPosition; b++)
{
    itemsOnList[b] = itemsOnList[b+1];
}
```

`b` can range up to `arrayPosition` - 1, so `itemsOnList[b+1]` can be written as `itemsOnList[arrayPosition-1+1]` or as `itemsOnList[arrayPosition]`. `arrayPosition` may be one past the end of the end of the list if the list was full.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanations. Very informative and I learned several new things! Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has three stand-out issues.

**No initialization of 'arraySize' and 'arrayPosition'.**

You don't specify an initial value for 'arraySize' but you do specify

```
    Item* itemsOnList = new Item[arraySize];
```

Because of the way you have specified this, at best it will always produce a zero-length (nullptr) itemsOnList, at worst it will use some uninitialized and thus random value to create a randomly sized array, and arrayPosition will also be randomly smaller or larger than the arraySize value.

**size *= 2**

```
if (arrayPosition == arraySize)
{
    //doubling arraySize since we need more space
    arraySize *= 2;
```

In the best-case scenario, your arraySize starts as zero. Thus when you double it, you get: zero.

**Deletion of everything.**

In addItem, you do the following:

```
    delete[] itemsOnList;

    //transferring data from temp List back to Old list
    itemsOnList = tempList;
```

at this point, both itemsOnList and tempList point to the same array. So the next statement:

```
    delete[] tempList;
```

deletes your second copy - now both the old and new arrays are deleted.